# Change destination for ms teams link

Tags: windows, regedit

I want to change app for opening ms teams link. I think that command for opening store to the register, but if I change command to my app and restart PC, I see in register my command, but if I open ms teams link, my command is not work and teams is launch and open this link

Path for changed command:

```
HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT->msteams->shell-> open->command
```

Maybe, I need to do some additional work, but I don't know what. My question: What I need to do for change app for opening ms teams link?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are multiple entries in the registry for MS Teams. Try updating the following registry paths:

```
Computer\HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Classes\msteams\shell\open\command

Computer\HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Classes\ms-teams\shell\open\command

Computer\HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Classes\TeamsURL\shell\open\command
```

Looks like the last one is what you actually need.

Comment: Also using this help helps me
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/shell/default-programs